# Python REST API in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an extra API which I need to access using my Python REST client (OAuth and tokens are everything sorted). But I would like to invoke this python client in my Data Factory as I want to store the results into Azure SQL warehouse.

Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a custom activity, this way you can run a Python script with Data Factory. For this you need to create an extra resource, Azure Batch.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-python-tutorial#batch-python-tutorial-code-sample

If you dont like that option, you can use a Web activity, that also calls a custom REST api. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin. It helped.

Comment: Hi Martin, Just a follow up question. I have also setup Dataset as Http File. It can also reach the endpoint and extract the results. I am confused which one should I choose?

Comment: You mean like its explained here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http I think this is the easier way, i would use a custom activity for more complex stuff than getting data from an http, so definitely for with the http dataset and copy activity

Comment: Correct. What kind of complex stuff you are talking about that can be done in custom activity and not in http dataset? I am comparitively new to Factory actually.